# Custom wordpress plugin : some JS functions are ignored (priority problem)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I created a custom plugin in which I have a .js file with some jQuery functions.
These functions all work fine from the admin.

Now I need to add a form (ACF) on the frontend, so I created a single post template for my post type, added the form. My jQuery scripts weren't taken into account, so I added on top of the php template :

```
<script src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1" id="jquery-core-js"></script>
```

Now most of my jQuery functions work, except for those involving a date picker. After narrowing down the problem i understood that it was a simple priority problem. If I enqueue the script in my theme's function.php, then all works just fine ; I could do that for now, but it defeats the purpose of having all the files in a plugin (if I change theme, I'd have to think of re-enqueuing the script in my functions file.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: If you can share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you're facing we might be able to help. Otherwise and without seeing some actual code all we can do is take guesses.

Comment: You can enqueue js from your plugin as well.